# private Pod install

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have created my own custom private pod on github and when try to install the pod on same system it is working fine, but when i try to install that pod in another system getting this error.[image]

My podfile is :- [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the user on the other system has read access to the pod repository.

Comment: is there any another option to do this ? as we don't want to provide the read access to anyone.

Comment: You can distribute a binary framework instead of the source code. See https://github.com/bielikb/xcframeworks for explanations and sample code.